# TO_DATE to YYYYMMDD from DD-MON-YY

Tags: mysql, sql, database, oracle, to-date

I have some data in the following date format. 
'27-SEP-97' i.e DD-MON-YY

Now I want to convert this to YYYYMMDD. I am using the following script to convert this.

```
TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(CHD_DATE_FIRST_ACT,'DD-MON-YY'),'YYYYMMDD')
```

but this is giving me the following output.

```
20970927
```

I want this data to be in YYYYMMDD format, such that the output looks like this- **19970927**

Comment: Oracle or MySQL? Please tag only the RDBMS you need.

Comment: How does the database could know whether `97` means 1997 or 2097? - [Year 2000 problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2000_problem), unbelievable that this problem still exist. I think the main reason is: majority of current software developers were still babies when the Y2K problem was by far the most debated topic in entire IT world.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit: *unbelievable that this problem still exist*, well, it's more than 80 years to the next century break :-) Actually two-digit years are getting more common again.

Comment: Could be best before dates. _Can I drink this milk - I don't know if it is from 2018 or 1918?_

Comment: @dnoeth, I assume the next wave of problems will arrive already around 2050 because people use format `RR` as solution. Luckily I will be retired at this time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If '27-SEP-97' is a string (which is what your words suggest), then such a combination of TO_this and TO_that might do the job:

```
SQL> with test as (select '27-SEP-97' datum from dual)
  2  select to_char(to_date(datum, 'dd-mon-rr', 'nls_date_language = english'), 'yyyymmdd') result
  3  from test;

RESULT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
19970927

SQL>
```

Comment: This was helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

--USE RR instead of YY in your query.

select TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('27-SEP-97','DD-MON-RR'),'YYYYMMDD') from dual;

Comment: This was helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of mysql `replace` and `str_to_date` functions
`replace` takes 3 arguments as show below
`replace(string,find_string,replace_with)`
you should simply replace `-` with a blank string
if your str is '27-SEP-97' to get the output as `19970927` execute the following in mysql

`select replace(str_to_date('27-SEP-97','%d-%b-%Y'),'-','') as date;`
output

```
+----------+
| date     |
+----------+
| 19970927 |
+----------+
```

`%b` is used to mention abbreviated month name

click the below links to know more about mysql date and time functions
**[Mysql Data and Time functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html)**

Comment: This was helpful. Thank you!

Comment: @ShubhamSharan , glad I could help